# Open weather API

Tags: html, json, weather-api

So, I'm making a bunch of webpages for different communities, and on each I want to have a little weather box that I can customize, just with the name of the town, the current temperature, and the current weather condition. I want to be able to style it all exactly how I want. I found this site called [Open Weather Map](http://openweathermap.org/) that seems to do exactly what I want. The problem is that I don't know how to use JSON. It's probably easy, but I seem to have gotten lost on any online tutorials I've tried.

This is an example of a URL for the page, that loads some JSON. http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk

I could just include this in my file and dynamically change the city and the country code to get the city I want. But how do I load this into my weather box? Let's say this is what I have:

```
<div class="weatherbox">

  <strong class="city>{CITY NAME HERE}</strong>
  <span class="temperature">{X} °C</span>
  <p class="weatherdescription>{WEATHER DESCRIPTION HERE}</p>

</div>
```

Then how do I access the data from the JSON? I want it to be done as simply as possible. Do I include the file like this to have access to the object, or is it more complicated?

```
<script type="javascript" src="http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk"></script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

from your line of code:

```
<script type="javascript" src="http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk"></script>
```

this is incorrect, the api is returning JSON, it is not a javascript file so you don't access it in such a manner.  Note that their API appears to take the city and country as a part of the URL parameters, so this you will need to plug in for the appropriate city/country.

For your specific question you could do something like:

```
var jsonData;

$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $.getJSON('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk', function(data) {
        jsonData = data;
        $('.city').text(jsonData.name);
        // etc
    });
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/jsxm7j3n/1/ for it in action.

Note in order to understand the JSON, you can run it through a JSON parser such as the one at http://json.parser.online.fr/ - this will allow you to better understand the make up of what you're receiving back, and how to parse it.

Double note: forgot to mention this solution uses JQuery - i believe there are purely javascript ways to pull it off, but it will be much more verbose and (in my opinion) harder to understand.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming jQuery:

```
<script>
// Load the data through ajax, not by including it like a script:

$.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk', function(data) {
    $('.weatherbox .temperature').text(data.main.temp);
});

</script>
```

When you look at the response headers from the URL to the API, it is sending 2 important headers:

```
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

This means:

1. Return JSON object, not just a file. You don't have to use `JSON.parse()` or `$.getJSON` then.
2. Allow anyone to request it via ajax (security aspect of Ajax).

Because Ajax by default is async, (that's what the A stands for), you need to wrap your assignment into a function, which is executed after the request has finished.

Answer (score 0):

The following Code runs. You must only change the Api Key

A full Tutorial: https://www.revilodesign.de/blog/sonstiges/wetterdaten-mit-openweathermap-api-in-eigene-webseite-einbinden/

```js
// API URL
var apiUrl    = 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&units=metric&APPID=YOUR_API_KEY';

// AJAX
jQuery.ajax ({
 url: apiUrl,
 type: 'GET',
 dataType: 'jsonp',
 success: function(data) {

  console.log(data);

  // COORDINATES
  var coordLat   = data.coord.lat;
  var coordLng   = data.coord.lon;
  
  // WEATHER
  var weatherId   = data.weather[0].id;
  var weatherMain   = data.weather[0].main;
  var weatherDesc   = data.weather[0].description;
  var weatherIcon   = '<img src="https://openweathermap.org/img/w/' + data.weather[0].icon + '.png" />';
  var weatherBg   = data.weather[0].icon;
  
  // BASE
  var baseData   = data.base;
  
  // TEMP
  var mainTemp   = data.main.temp;
  var mainPressure  = data.main.pressure;
  var mainHumidity  = data.main.humidity;
  var mainTempMin   = data.main.temp_min;
  var mainTempMax   = data.main.temp_max;
  
  // VISIBILITY
  var visibility   = data.visibility;
  
  // WIND
  var windSpeed   = data.wind.speed;
  var windDeg    = data.wind.deg;
  
  // CLOUDS
  var clouds    = data.clouds.all;
  
  // DT
  var dt     = data.dt;
  
  // SYS
  var sysType    = data.sys.type;
  var sysId    = data.sys.id;
  var sysMessage   = data.sys.message;
  var sysCountry   = data.sys.country;
  var sysSunrise   = data.sys.sunrise;
  var sysSunset   = data.sys.sunset;
  
  // ID
  var id     = data.id;
  
  // NAME
  var name    = data.name;
  
  // COD
  var cod     = data.cod;
     
  jQuery('#city').html( name );
  jQuery('#temp').html( mainTemp + '° C' );
  jQuery('#desc').html( weatherDesc );
 }
 
});
```

```css
#weatherbox {
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #b4ecff;
  border-radius: 8px;
  display: table;
  margin: 20px auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
  overflow:hidden;
  padding: 0 0 10px 0;
}
strong,
span {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin: 0;
}
p {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0
}
strong {
  background: #00769d;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="weatherbox">

  <strong id="city"></strong>
  <span id="temp"></span>
  <p id="desc"></p>

</div>
```