# Why does storing Open Weather Api fetched data in saved state not render in React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

I've been using Open Weather's Api to fetch data and store it into a saved state in React JS in order to call the saved state and render the actual weather data on my web app. Here's the problem, I can console.log the api data that is stored in the function variable with no problem, I can even pass the api data directly into the state, and then into my web app. However, when I try to pass the api data into a variable, and then save that to the state and render it, I get an error of "TypeError: Unable to get property 'temp' of undefined or null reference". The reason I do not understand that is if I take that same "null reference" snippet, and try to console log it inside the function, it returns the data! What exactly am I doing wrong?

I'm still relatively new to ReactJS so to gain a better understanding to React JS api calls I read through Ethan Jerrel's article (which actually did help me alot) on fetching api data in react:
https://blog.hellojs.org/fetching-api-data-with-react-js-460fe8bbf8f2

As Well as the following previous stack overflow questions concerning similar problems:

-Basic open weather api problem
[Open weather API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27639668/open-weather-api)

-problem with ajax call using open weather api
[Open Weather data in React using Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32898002/open-weather-data-in-react-using-ajax)

-Updating set state with api data
[updating set state in api call react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49164659/updating-set-state-in-api-call-react)

This is my code:

```
   import React, { Component } from 'react';
// import logo from '../logo.svg';
import '../App.css';

class Main extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      kyoto: [],
      kyotoMainWeather: [],
      kyotoTemp: [],
      kyotoDescription: [],

    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
 this.fetchData();


}

fetchData(){
  fetch('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=kyoto&units=imperial&APPID=63dd0d75cb039f76bb9b092405a90895')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
     console.log(data); //returns api data in object with no error

     var kyoto = data; //stores api data in var
     console.log(kyoto); // returns api data in object with no error

     var kyotoMainWeather = data.weather[0].main; //stores api data in var
     var kyotoTemp = data.main.temp; //stores api data in var
     var kyotoDescription = data.weather[0].description; //stores api data in var

      this.setState({kyoto: kyoto}); //stores api object data in saved state
      this.setState({kyotoMainWeather: kyotoMainWeather}); //stores api object data in saved state
      this.setState({kyotoTemp: kyotoTemp}); //stores api object data in saved state
      this.setState({kyotoDescription: kyotoDescription}); //stores api object data in saved state


  })
  .catch(error => console.log('parsing failed', error))


}



  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Body">
      <div className="row">
      <div className="col-sm-6">

      <div className="card bg-dark text-white">
  <img className="card-img" src={"https://images.pexels.com/photos/219000/pexels-photo-219000.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940"} alt="Weather Card"/>
  <div className="card-img-overlay d-flex align-items-end">
  <div className="card-row">
  <div className="temperature-city-container">
    <h5 className="weather-card-text">{this.state.kyoto.main.temp}&#176;</h5> // This is an actual data call which returns null in my web app, but when I console.log(kyoto.main.temp) it returns!
    <p className="temperature-undertext">Kyoto, Japan</p>
    </div>
    <p className="weather-card-secondary-text">{this.state.kyotoTemp}</p> // this returns the data with no error

    <p className="weather-card-secondary-text">{this.state.kyoto.main.temp}</p> // this is the same call (in theory) as the above "this.state.kyotoTemp" however it returns null, but when I console.log(kyoto.main.temp) it returns!
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

      </div>

      </div>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Main;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're rendering your component before the data is fetched. Try giving defaults to the data passed to the component, or check if data exists before rendering. Something like:

```
<h5 className="weather-card-text">
    {this.state.kyoto && this.state.kyoto.main && this.state.kyoto.main.temp}&#176;
</h5>
```

So you check that `kyoto` and then `kyto.main` exists on the state before trying to call properties from them.

Comment: I just attempted running that and received the same error "TypeError: Unable to get property 'temp' of undefined or null reference", did you mean perhaps running some kind of if statement?

Comment: What about `{this.state.kyoto &&  this.state.kyoto.main && this.state.kyoto.main.temp}`? 
That's checking the existence of each parent in the hierarchy, and returning true when they all exist.

Comment: That worked!!!! Thank you so much!!! How exactly does that work??? And why does it return the temp value? I don't see a "return" statement in there, yet it still returns it? How is that possible?

Comment: You're welcome! When looking for a property value that's deep in a tree-like structure, one often has to check whether intermediate nodes exist. This is why there is a [proposal for a syntax](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining) to do this in a (debatably) cleaner way.

My immediate guess is that react is re-rendering that particular component before each individual step in the tree gets loaded, whereas the variables you stored the result in already have that data on each re-render.

Comment: That makes sense!! you totally helped me out a lot! Thank you so much!!!